# Compare Multiple Variables to Same Value Efficiently

Tags: c#, conditional-statements

I'm looking for alternative methods in C# to compare multiple variables to the same value, and I would optimally like for them to share the same subsequent instructions based on their conditional results.

For example, I have the following code:

```
string DOBResultsError = VerifySingleRecordReturned(DOBResults, APIParameters, 1);
string NameResultsError = VerifySingleRecordReturned(NameResults, APIParameters, 2);

if (DOBResultsError != string.Empty)
{
    PatientRecordUpdate(DOBResults, APIParameters.PatientID, DOBResultsError);
}
else if (NameResultsError != string.Empty)
{
    PatientRecordUpdate(NameResults, APIParameters.PatientID, NameResultsError);
}
```

I'm having to do explicitly instruct `PatientRecordUpdate` to be performed for each variable being compared to `String.Null`.

What I would like to have happen is something like the following:

```
if (DOBResultsError != string.Empty || NameResultsError != string.Empty)
{
    //whichever isn't an empty string use to perform PatientRecordUpdate()
}
```

Is such syntax possible in C#?

Employing the `switch` keyword won't make a difference because even though I can have multiple circumstances resulting in the same instructions being performed, if I need to use the one of the comparison variables I would still need to explicitly state the code using the variable for each possible case.

```
string DOBResultsError = VerifySingleRecordReturned(DOBResults, APIParameters, 1);
string NameResultsError = VerifySingleRecordReturned(NameResults, APIParameters, 2);
string SSNResultsError = VerifySingleRecordReturned(SSNResults, APIParameters, 3);
string EmptyString = String.Empty;

switch (EmptyString)
{
    case DOBResultsError:
    case SSNResultsError: //can't use SSNResultsError with PatientRecordUpdate() without stating PatientRecordUpdate() again
        PatientRecordUpdate(DOBResults, APIParameters.PatientID, DOBResultsError);

    case NameResultsError:
        PatientRecordUpdate(NameResults, APIParameters.PatientID, NameResultsError);
}
```

Any help appreciated.

**UPDATE: Requested additional info**

This is what VerifySingleRecordReturnedFrom() does. It checks a few conditions that would cause errors in the program and writes an error message to be added on the record in an SQL DB.

```
public static string VerifySingleRecordReturnedFrom(List<PatientList3> ReturnedPatientList, AutoPatientLookup APIParameters, int SearchCriteria = 0)
        {
            string ErrorMessage = String.Empty;
            if (ReturnedPatientList.Count == 0)
            {
                //Error Message for Dob
                if (SearchCriteria == 1)
                {
                    ErrorMessage = string.Format("No patients were returned from  for DOB ....");
                    return ErrorMessage;
                }
                //Error Message for Name
                else if (SearchCriteria == 2)
                {
                    ErrorMessage = string.Format("No patients were returned from  for patient name ....");
                    return ErrorMessage;
                }
                //Error Message for PracticePatientNumber
                else if (SearchCriteria == 3)
                {
                    ErrorMessage = string.Format("No patients were returned from  for PracticePatientNumber...");
                    return ErrorMessage;
                }
            }
            // more than one patient in common results list from AttemptToMatchPatientsByDemographics() or  results using PatientNumber
            else if (ReturnedPatientList.Count() > 1)
            {
                switch(SearchCriteria)
                {
                    case 1:
                    case 2:
                        ErrorMessage = String.Format("{0} number of patients were returned...");
                        break;

                    //More than one patient returned from  for any given PracticePatientNumber
                    case 3:
                        ErrorMessage = String.Format("{0} number of patients were returned....");
                        break;
                }
                return ErrorMessage;
            }
            //No error in number of results from 
            return ErrorMessage;
        }
```

All of the results(DOB/Name/SSN) types are List objects of the following PatientList3 object (I've included sub classes):

```
public class PatientList3
        {
            public Patient PatientNameID { get; set; }
            public string PatientNumber { get; set; }
            public string ChartNumber { get; set; }
            public Gender2 Gender { get; set; }
            public string DOB { get; set; }
            public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
            public string SSN { get; set; }
        }

public class Patient
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public PtName Name { get; set; }
        }

public class PtName
        {
            public string First { get; set; }
            public string Middle { get; set; }
            public string Last { get; set; }
            public string Suffix { get; set; }
            public string Full { get; set; }
            public string Preferred { get; set; }
        }
public class Gender2
        {
            public string LookupType { get; set; }
            public string Code { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public int Order { get; set; }
            public bool Active { get; set; }
            public List<AlternateCodes> AlternateCodes { get; set; } //Not important, didn't include AlternativeCodes class
        }
```

This is the class of APIParameters:

```
public class AutoPatientLookup
        {
            public string DOB { get; set; }
            public string Gender { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public int? PatientNumber { get; set; }
            public string SSN { get; set; }
            public int PracticeID { get; set; }
            public int PatientID { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: Could you please share the code what `VerifySingleRecordReturned` does and what are the types of input parameters `DOBResults` and  `APIParameters`? That might help us to propose something.

Comment: You can use a `List<Tuple<Results, string>>`, assuming each of the `Results` objects inherit from the same base class or implement the same interface named `Results`.

Comment: Do `DOBResults` and `NameResults` and `SSNResults` the same type?

Comment: *"optimally like for them to share the same subsequent instructions based on their conditional results"* -- can you restate that sentence so a five year old could understand it?

Comment: @DmitryPavlov I've updated the question with the info you requested

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I think I see what you mean. They all inherit from the same class so I think your suggestion would be possible. Would you suggestion require a foreach loop and a single if clause?

Comment: @CodeNotFound Yes they are. See question update for additional details.

Comment: `foreach` loop would work, yes. You could also use `.Where().ToList().ForEach()` if you prefer that coding style, though it's definitely not necessary here.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Sorry about that. I'm not really sure how to properly phrase my question. Does "I want the same action performed for each item being tested when the test is the same for each item" sound more clear?

Comment: @W.Harr No, but I went back and read the code again. Seems you want to put all your results in a collection, then loop through it, checking for errors on each one. That must be what CodeNotFound was getting at when he asked if all the results were of the same type. S.C.'s answer is in essence what I'd suggest.

Answer (score -1):

Consider leveraging a base result type for some generic logic like this:

```
// assuming both results inherit from or implement some base type...
List<ResultBase> results = new List<ResultBase>()
{
    DOBResults,
    NameResults 
}; // order matters since it's used for the parameter index

// Note that a class would be a much better option than a tuple here.
// Select will verify each result but only upon request until FirstOrDefault is fulfilled
Tuple<ResultBase, string> firstResultError = results
    .Select((result, index) => new Tuple<ResultBase, string>(
        result,
        VerifySingleRecordReturned(result, APIParameters, index + 1)))
    .FirstOrDefault(result => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Item2 /* Error message */));

// If there was at least one error, call the original patient update record
// with the associated information.
if (firstResultError != null)
{
    PatientRecordUpdate(
        firstResultError.Item1 /* Failed result */,
        APIParameters.PatientID,
        firstResultError.Item2 /* Error message for that result */);
}
```

You'll want to use a new class instead of a tuple for maintainability reasons, but besides that this should get you started in a good direction.

Comment: I think `PatientRecordUpdate` is meant to be called with *each* error -- so `FirstOrDefault` should be `Where`, and `if (firstResultError != null) {...}` should be a `foreach` loop. I didn't dv but I think that's an error in your answer.

Comment: OPs original code used an `else if` and his goal pseudocode uses the term "whichever". Both of those imply they are only interested in setting the first error and not an aggregate or an overwrite. Thanks for the comment, though.

Comment: Good point, I missed that `else`. Possibly I'm not the only one.